# Unity PerRequestLifetimeManager UnitTest

Tags: unit-testing, unity-container

I have following Unity configuration:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        ...
        container.RegisterType<IRootDatabaseContext, RootEntities>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        ...
    }
```

And everything works fine. But when I also want to test this method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AssertUnityConfigAreValid()
{
    using (var container = new UnityContainer())
    {
        UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(container);
        foreach (var registration in container.Registrations)
        {
            container.Resolve(registration.RegisteredType, registration.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run this test I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException - Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

How can I replace LifeTimeManager into Unit test from PerRequestLifetimeManager to another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found the solution for this issue:

Just need to add following code before this line in test

> UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(container);

```
var request = new HttpRequest("fake", "https://127.0.0.1", null);
var respons = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
var context = new HttpContext(request, respons);
HttpContext.Current = context;
```